# Hybrid Graphics. How to enable the second card

Tags: hybrid-graphics

I should Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. 
Lenovo g505s 
Tas worth two cards: 
[Radeon HD 8650G] integrated graphics 
and [Radeon HD 8570A / 8570M] 
I have not switched to the 8570M. 
Help resolve this issue.

just put

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

poprietarnye drivers are. But I determined only integrated graphics. 8570M does not want to run. How do I start it?

[lshw](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ombpZfrwhNs_XYdvl7VZWOrk5fVYCU2Q1g2afkF6t8U/edit?usp=sharing)

[lspci -v](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HCYRheZS1SGW3WnHxFB9eWtnfgb5BivR2ZHc3j3Hdfg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to switch between the AMD v-cards with fglrs driver:

1. Use 'aticonfig' command with one of the options under your root:

--px-dgpu
       Activate discrete GPU (High-Performance mode), must re-start X to take effect

--px-igpu
       Activate integrated GPU (Power-Saving mode), must re-start X to take effect

2. Run 'amdcccle' under your user account and choose the v-card you want then re-start X-server.